# How can I implement type testing for reference types and value types supporting null?

Tags: c#, generics, null

I try to implement type testing which supports null.

I have two generic functions:

```cs
public static int FromValueType<T>(T? o) where T : struct { /* do stuff */ return 1; }
public static int FromClassType<T>(T o) where T : class { /* do stuff */ return 2; }
```

I understand that neither of the two can support `null` because the compiler can not infer `T` from `null`. For example, this call won't work:

```cs
var x = FromClassType(null);
```

This is why I would like to write a wrapper which implements type testing to extend the functionality for `null`.

What i have tried so far:

```cs
public static int From(object o)
{
    return o switch
    {
        null => 0,
        /**
         * TODO: Compiler complains:
         *   The type arguments for method 'int MyModule.FromValueType<T>(T?)' 
         *   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
         *   explicitly.
         */
        ValueType oValueType => FromValueType(oValueType),
        _ => FromClassType(o)
   };
}
```

But this does not work either.

If `ValueType` is a base class for all value types, why can the compiler not infer `T`?

Comment: What would you expect it to infer `T` to be? Bear in mind that the type inference has to be at compile-time.... the type argument will be present in the IL.

Comment: Note how in this approach you are calling `FromClassType<object>`, not `FromClassType<ActualTypeOf_o>`, so it's flawed anyway.

Comment: And by the way, your methods do "support null". For example `FromClassType<string>(null);`, or `string x = null; FromClassType(x)`

Comment: @JonSkeet I would expect T to be some base type for all value types.

Comment: @Evk, what I meant with "can support null" is `FromClassType(null)`

Comment: And why would you ever want to call it with literal `null` constant? I understand if you call it passing object which happens to be null, but just passing null there? What's the point? But anyway you can maybe just add `FromNull()` then.

Comment: @Evk, I am perfectly ok when `From` calls `FromClassType<object>`.

Comment: "I would expect T to be some base type for all value types" - which type in particular? It can't be `System.ValueType` because that's a reference type, so doesn't satisfy the condition that `T` is a value type. I know it's a bit confusing for System.ValueType to be a reference type...

Comment: Would be better if you describe what those methods actually do. If you don't care about `T` (you are fine with calling `FromClassType<object>` ) then maybe you don't need generics at all?

Comment: Your wrapper is kinda useless since it would always box, meaning there's no point to delegating to value- or reference-specific methods; just implement what you need directly in `From(object)`, which also supports anything.

Comment: Not sure what the actual problem is but if the only problem you are trying to solve is that for some reason you need to call `FromClassType(null)` you can just add a non-generic overload for `FromClassType` - `public static int FromClassType(object o){...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.ValueType` is a reference type. Therefore the compile can not infer a matching version of:

```
public static int FromValueType<T>(T? o) where T : struct { /* do stuff */ return 1; }
```

As far as I know, there exists no common base type for all value types. This means we have to use reflection to build and call `FromValueType` at runtime:

```cs
public static int From(object o)
{   
    return o switch
    {
        null => 0,
        ValueType oValueType => (int) typeof(ClassWithFromValueTypeMethod)
            .GetMethod(nameof(FromValueType))
            ?.MakeGenericMethod(oValueType.GetType())
            .Invoke(null, new []{o}),
        _ => FromClassType(o) 
    };  
}
```

Using reflection in this situation might not be optimal but its the only solution I can see that works without refactoring `FromValueType` and `FromClassType`.

If we can can refactor `FromValueType` and `FromClassType`. It is probably best to simply move the logic from the two inside the `From` wrapper:

```cs
public static int From<T>(T o)
{   
    if (o == null) return 0;
    return typeof(T).IsValueType
        ? 1  // FromValueType
        : 2; // FromClassType
}
```

Note that depending on the complexity of `FromValueType` and `FromClassType` this might be a less ideal solution in terms of testability and maintainabilty. Also it does not support calling it with `null`. To support that, we have to do some runtime type checking again:

```cs
public static int From(object o)
{   
    if (o == null) return 0;
    return o.GetType().IsValueType
        ? 1  // FromValueType
        : 2; // FromClassType
}
```

---

Thank you @JonSkeet for your helpful comment.